# TYPO3 Powermail double opt-in for newsletter only

Tags: typo3, powermail

I've got a contact form. In this form I want to add a "newsletter Opt-In".
This Opt-In has to be double opt-in.

The Problem:

- I can set double opt-in
- Once this is set, the whole form becomes double opt in

  - The user has to confirm the form, not the newsletter opt in
  - Only when the user confirms the form, the contact form mail is sent

So obviously this is the wrong behaviour. I want the formdata to be sent immediately, but a second mail for the newsletter opt-in.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I remember the TypoScript setup `plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.main.optin=1` or `=0` will enable or disable Optin in powermail.
Together with a condition where you listen to a GET/POST if a checkbox is set, you can enable or disable it.

Answer (score 2):

I only know of a solution for the following behaviour: 
If the user does not check the Option checkbox, the formdata will be sent immediately to the receiver. If the Optin checkbox is checked, the formdata won't be sent before the user confirms the email. After confirmation the email with the formdata (containing the fielddata `newslettersubscription = 1`) will be sent to the receiver.

You can use a typoscript condition to check if the newsletter Opt-In checkbox was checked. If the markername of your checkbox is for example `newslettersubscription` you could use the follwing condition in your typoscript setup.

```
#disable option
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.main.optin = 0
#enable option if option checkbox is checked
[globalVar = GP:tx_powermail_pi1|field|newslettersubscription|0 > 0]
  plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.main.optin = 1
[end]
```

For this to work you have to setup your form with the following settings.

- "Double Optin" must not be set in the flex form settings
- Within the tab "Mail to User" the fields "Sender Name" and "Sender Email" have to be filled
- Your checkbox has to use the markername `newslettersubscription`

Comment: You have to use ```globalString``` instead of ```globalVar``` if you want to check for POST data.